# Does IOC container makes object's when project is deployed?

Tags: spring, ioc-container

How IOC container helps maintaing objects by creating once and injecting when required???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the spring reference about [Bean Scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) and about [Lazy Initialization](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init):

> By default, ApplicationContext 
>   implementations eagerly create and
>   configure all singleton beans as part
>   of the initialization process.
>   Generally, this pre-instantiation is
>   desirable, because errors in the
>   configuration or surrounding
>   environment are discovered
>   immediately, as opposed to hours or
>   even days later. When this behavior is
>   not desirable, you can prevent
>   pre-instantiation of a singleton bean
>   by marking the bean definition as
>   lazy-initialized. A lazy-initialized
>   bean tells the IoC container to create
>   a bean instance when it is first
>   requested, rather than at startup.
>
> In XML, this behavior is controlled by
>   the lazy-init attribute on the 
>   element; for example:

```
<bean id="lazy" class="com.foo.ExpensiveToCreateBean" lazy-init="true"/>

<bean name="not.lazy" class="com.foo.AnotherBean"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you have configured the specific dependency, you can have singleton, per request, http etc lifecycles